# Is there any way to identify crossed out words in PDF file while parsing it using Python?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pymupdf

I am parsing PDF file using PyMuPDF (great library by the way!)

But I need to identify words, that are crossed out.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: can you include a sample pdf?

Answer (score 0):

PyMUPDF docs do not seem to talk about crossed out (strike-out), except when dealing with annotations, but they do talk about these "flags".

```
bit 0: superscripted (20)
bit 1: italic (21)
bit 2: serifed (22)
bit 3: monospaced (23)
bit 4: bold (24)
```

So there might well be a code for strike-out that is not listed in the docs.

One way to access these codes is via the textPage dictionary structure using the spam tag. For more info on this see `6.18.1.4 Span Dictionary` in the docs.

I wanted to pulled bold text out of documents and wrote this function

```
def get_bold_text_from_PDF_page(page_number):
    '''
    Function to get bold text from PyMUPDF Page object
    Parameters:
            PyMUPDF doc generator object
    Returns:
            list of dictionaries each dictionary contains these fields:
            Size, flags, font, color, ascender, decender, text, origin, bbox, page_number
    '''
    blocks = fitz.Page.get_text(page_number, "dict", flags=11)["blocks"]
    page_bold_text_list = []
    for block in blocks:  
        for line in block["lines"]: 
            for span in line["spans"]: 
                if span['flags'] == 20:  # change the 20 here.
                    span['page_number'] = page.number  
                    page_bold_text_list.append(span)
                    print(page_bold_text_list)
    return page_bold_text_list
```

Strangely for me 20 was bold.

This Adobe docs might be worth a read
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf